# IOS 8 Button background image checking not working

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uibutton, ios8

Button background image checking is failing in IOS 8, it is working proper in IOS7 and earlier.

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButon*)tempbutton
{
//working in IOS 7 but broken in IOS 8
if(tempbutton.currentBackgroundImage ==[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]){


}
}
```

Comment: This is not good practice of comparing images.Use Custom button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try comparing the `UIImage` returned by the `backgroundImageForState:` instead of the `UIButton` imageView property.

```
if ([[tempbutton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed@"uncheck.png"]]){
  // Button has a background image named 'uncheck.png'
} else{
  // Button has not a background image named 'uncheck.png'
}
```

A best way to check if a button is selected or not, is to used your button's state, like `UIButtonStateNormal`, or `UIButtonStateSelected`. You can just change its selection like that:

```
[tempbutton setSelected:![self.btnMenu isSelected]];
```

In addition, set the right image following your button's state in your xib or in code if you create it programatically:

```
[self.tempbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.tempbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```